# Changining navigation bar items content without affecting views content

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, ios9

Is there a common pattern to change navigation bar contents without changing UITableView content, scroll position, other elements etc?

I have a Navigation bar with a title and a button. On press of this button I wish the bar to display a text box instead of the title and another button with another action. On tap outside text bar or button segue unwinds.

The obvious way is to push a segue to another scene without animation, reimplement the same UITableView content and position, but I find this quite inefficient.

Another way is to try doing it on the same scene. I tried to place text box on the title's place of navigation bar. In this case text box replaces navigation bar's label and does not let it show even if text box gets hidden.

iOS 8-9 + Swift
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the titleview of the navigation item of your controller to the desired view

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let titleView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 64.0))
    let titleLabel : UILabel = UILabel (frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 34.0))
    titleLabel.text = "title"
    let button : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 40.0, 20.0))

    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleView .addSubview(button)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! This is exactly what I did too. Hardcoding still has few "but" including manual constrains adding etc.
I'm looking for an, say, Apple-way solution (maybe creating an array of navigation bar classes and switching between them) that benefits from storyboard design and auto layout to evade possible future issues.